# Nightlife or night life (BrE)

Tags: british-english, orthography

What is the correct spelling of the word "*nightlife*" (e.g. *social activities in clubs/bars*) in British English?

Is it nightlife (one word) or night life (two words)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to answer these type of questions is to reach for a corpus. Since this particular question is about en-gb the relevant corpus is the [British National Corpus](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/), which gives 134 hits for "nightlife" and 42 for "night life". So either is acceptable, but the single-word version appears to be preferred.

Answer (score 2):

The Oxford English Dictionary (2nd ed.) has only **night-life**. However, all its quotes but one spell *night life*; it may be that the definition is more up to date than the quotes.

> 1852 *H. Melville Pierre xvi. i. 322*
>   All the garish **night-life** of a
>   vast thoroughfare, crowded and wedged
>   by day, and even now, at this late
>   hour, brilliant with occasional
>   illuminations.
>
> 1913 *H. L. Mencken Let. 17 Aug.
>   (1961) 32* The title ‘**Night Life**
>   in Vienna’...has the air of a lure held
>   out to the Puritanical and
>   dirty-minded.
>
> 1927 *G. Ade et al. Let. 4 Mar. (1973)
>   119* Our fellow-passengers...were ashore
>   last night, dancing and hunting up a
>   second-rate African imitation of
>   **night life** in Paris.
>
> 1929 *D. L. Moore Pandora's Letter Box
>   iii. 53* ‘**Night life**’—to use the
>   popular expression for habitual
>   nocturnal dancing and drinking.
>
> 1972 *Sat. Rev. (U.S.) 25 Mar. 68/3*
>   The Kabarett, with its sharp political
>   satire, was part of Berlin **night
>   life**.

Comment: Look at the dates though :D 1913, 1927, 1929, 1972...

Comment: @Alenanno: That's why I said the definition may be more up to date than the quotes.

Comment: @Alenanno: Oh, I see what you mean. I assumed spelling might have shifted back to *night-life* since 1972, to be reflected in the definition; but it might as well be the other way around. In any case, this question is exceedingly trivial...

Comment: It's probably the strangest word in the language. There is no right way to spell it.

Comment: @IlyaBiryukov: Oh, but there are countless more! The thing is, whether a combination of *noun + noun* or *adjective + noun* is written attached, hyphenated, or separated is hardly logical; it's mostly an arbitrary convention and depends on the word. There are no clear rules.

Comment: @Cerberus, yes, I understand that. Anything that's been around for long enough is a mess :) 
But even though there might not be any logical background to something, there at least should be a documented guidelines of use of some sort. In this case, how to spell a word. 
You see, we're making a company video with the word "nightlife" in the centre of everything in huge font (we have our reasons :). It would be a total embarrassment to misspell the most important word in the video.

Comment: @IlyaBiryukov: Understandable. In your place, I'd just look up similar cases in any major dictionary: if it's in at least one, it will certainly be acceptable.

Comment: @Ilya: Cerberus is right - the flipside of it being unclear whether it is better to write "nightlife", "night-life" or "night life" is that native speakers are generally used to seeing all variations, and usually won't even notice if you use one different from what they would have written.

Answer (score 1):

My NOAD gives it as one word:

> **nightlife** |ˈnītˌlīf|
>   noun
>   social activities or entertainment available at night in a town or city.

No comment about British vs. American, either.

Comment: I tend to think the same. What's putting me off, is Firefox's dictionary, that suggests night life (two words) for British and nightlife (one word) for American.

Comment: Also the [OALD](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/nightlife) gives it as one word.

Comment: What's with all you people using localized dictionaries? Oh well, the spelling of *nightlife/night-life/night life* hardly matters; I feel it's more of an arbitrary choice.

Comment: What do you mean by localized?

Comment: @Cerberus: What's with all you people referring to "all you people" when only one person made any reference at all to a localized dictionary (and the reference itself was not explicit) ;=P.

Comment: @Robusto: Oops! I assumed all those A's were [local](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=meF7NmfnXZ0).